# Doctrine2 commit order when removing entities

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a Symfony3 project using Doctrine 2.6 to manage the database.

I get an `Integrity constraint violation` error when I call the `remove` method the `EntityManager` **in a certain order**.

I've always considered this method (as well as `persist`) to work no matter in which order entities are passed to them, I was wrong.

The database runs on MySQL and has the following structure:

[image: Database schema]

The goal is to remove a `Menu` entity. I've simplified the case so the `Menu` is only linked to one `Offer`, and one `Component`.

The offer is linked to the same `Component` as the menu.

So it looks like this:

```
- Menu [#12 Menu Of the Day]
|  - Component [#23 Dessert]
|  |  - Product [#14 Pineapple]
|  - Offer [#42 Dessert only]
|  |  - Component [#23 Dessert]
|  |  |  - Product [#14 Pineapple]
```

Now this is the code that crashes :

```php
$em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
$menu = $em->getRepository(Menu::class)->findOneBy(['ref' => 'V0dQ']);

// Remove menu components (ex: starter, dish, dessert, etc.)
$menuComponents = $menu->getComponents();
$menuComponent = $menuComponents[0];
$menu->removeComponent($menuComponent);

// Remove components products
$componentsProducts = $menuComponent->getComponentProducts();
$componentProduct = $componentsProducts[0];
$menuComponent->removeComponentProduct($componentProduct);

// Remove offers (ex: start + dish, dish + dessert, etc.)
$offers = $menu->getOffers();
$offer = $offers[0];
$menu->removeOffer($offer);

// Same as menu components
$offerComponents = $offer->getComponents();
$offerComponent = $offerComponents[0];
$offer->removeComponent($offerComponent);

// Everything MUST be persisted/removed in one place.
$em->remove($componentProduct);
$em->remove($menuComponent);
$em->remove($offer);
$em->remove($offerComponent);
$em->remove($menu);

$em->flush();
```

I works by putting the call to `remove($menuComponent)` **after** the call to `remove($offer)`, like so:

```php
$em->remove($componentProduct);
$em->remove($offer);
$em->remove($menuComponent);
$em->remove($offerComponent);
$em->remove($menu);
```

This is a raw example of the problem. In reality I have a pretty complex "Api engine" (like Api Platform) in which everything is handled in a generic way.

I need a clear understanding of what happens to abstract a solution to any case in the future, that's where I call for your help.

Do you see a simple rule to determine which entity must be passed to `remove()` first?

Comment: Pls read all the answers in the duplicate topic, they describe different options on handling deletetions in multiple tables with parent-child relationships.

Comment: Thanks but the question you reference is a simple OneToMany relationship where the author inverted the foreign key. I have no problem with this kind of relations. The problem here is that I have two entities referencing the same one (Component) and I can't figure out a logical way to determine which one should be removed first. When removing the menu, should I remove the component or the offer first ? If I choose the offer, it works, otherwise it crashes. That's not the same problem.

Comment: Nope, you have the same simple parent- child relationship, just you have multiple of them. The same rules apply as in the other case.

Comment: You're right, it's only a matter of finding which entity should be removed first. It still blows my mind that Doctrine doesn't do it internally, but whatever. I've made a function in my Api to order generically any set of entities based on their relations, I would have posted the code in case it can help others but I can't post an answer. It may be because it is marked as duplicate..

Comment: I sugges you to read the answers in the duplicate question. There are db level solutions that can help you.

Comment: The question you keep referring to is about setting foreign keys in mysql. I do not set the foreign keys manually, Doctrine does it when the schema is updated. 
And as I already said, the author of the question inverted its foreign keys, and 90% of the answers are about correcting that, the other 10% are about disabling foreign keys checks, I don't see how it helps.
And again, I've already solved my problem by ordering the entities manually before calling `remove()`, and I can't post an answer because of the duplicate thing that I still don't understand.